# Can't find matcher.group(1) from the string

Tags: regex

This is the string:

```
Not enough money for withdraw of 140.82 USD. Need to fulfill bonuses of 139.82 USD. Current withdrawable amount: 2.33 USD
```

```
pattern.compile("Not enough credit for withdraw of \\d+(?:\\.\\d+)(?:\\s[A-Z]{3})?\\. Need to fulfill bonuses of \\d+(?:\\.\\d+)(?:\\s[A-Z]{3})?\\. Current withdrawable amount: \\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?");
```

This is the pattern which I am using but and I need a value of `matcher.group(1)`. Who can give me the last value `2.33 USD`?

Anyone help to correct my pattern.

Comment: You only have non capturing groups. Remove the `?:` from the groups you want to capture

Comment: Replace the end of your pattern with `(\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?(?:\\s[A-Z]{3})?)`

Answer (score 2):

Just add the pattern which matches the last number  inside a capturing group.

```
pattern.compile("Not enough money for withdraw of \\d+(?:\\.\\d+)(?:\\s[A-Z]{3})?\\. Need to fulfill bonuses of \\d+(?:\\.\\d+)(?:\\s[A-Z]{3})?\\. Current withdrawable amount: (\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?(?:\\s[A-Z]{3})?)");
                                                                                                                                                                                 ^                                ^
```

And also you need to change `credit` in your pattern to `money`

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/uR1mF4/4)

Answer (score 0):

The reason that your usual regex of
`\d+(?:\\.\\d+)(?:\\s[A-Z]{3})?\\.` doesn't work for the last group is simply because **it does not end in a period**. (`.`)

`\d+(?:\\.\\d+)(?:\\s[A-Z]{3})?` should work fine for it.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the string has a certain format, you don't need to exactly match the whole string, just the part you want, and you only need one line of code,

The simplest approach is

```
String withdrawable = str.replaceAll(".*?([.\\d]+) USD$", "$1");
```

This works because the target is at the end of the input. For a more general and expressive approach:

```
String withdrawable = str.replaceAll(".*withdrawable amount: ([.\\d]+).*", "$1");
```